# Which is the best django library that user can login my site use their facebook account 

Tags: python, django, facebook

i find three ways to do this :

```
1.django-facebookconnect
2.django-socialregistration
3.pyfacebook
```

which is better ,

thanks

Comment: django **is** a framework itself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This link can be useful: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/

I personally found existing apps bloated and inflexible (or just can't wrap my head around them) so I forked the most simple and well-written among them ( https://github.com/policus/django-registration-facebook-backend ) and implemented missing features (new Facebook JS api, account association and customizable profile pre-filling). The fork is on github.